# Hyperlink inside of a JEditorPane in a JOptionPane throwing a NullPointerException

Tags: java, html, hyperlink, nullpointerexception, jeditorpane

I am back with another issue.  I have done nothing with URL's and hyperlinks in Java before and have very little experience with html tagging. I have read tutorials and a lot of SO questions and can't seem to figure out why I am getting an exception thrown here.

So I have a program that I have added an "About" button to.  Clicking it opens a JOptionPane.  Inside the JOptionPane I have a JEditorPane with a whole bunch of text and at the end two hyperlinks for websites I am using as a source.  Now I have the links added and they are clickable, but when I click them, it throws a NullPointerException.  I am sure it has something to do with the ActionListener, I have tried several different ways of implementing with the same result.

What I would like to happen, is that when the link is clicked, it opens the default browser and navigates to the site.  Here is a test program that I wrote to try to debug, but includes the same code as my main.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;

public class HyperlinkTest extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton aboutButton = new JButton("About");

    public void aboutPopUp() throws IOException {

        final JEditorPane ep = new JEditorPane();

        ep.setEditable(false);
        ep.setEditorKit(JEditorPane.createEditorKitForContentType("text/html"));

        ep.setText("<html>Blah Blah<br />"
                + "Blah Blah<br />"
                + "Blah: <a href=\\\"\\\">http://exploration.grc.nasa.gov/education/rocket/rktcg.html</a><br />"
                + "Blah: <a href=\\\"\\\">http://exploration.grc.nasa.gov/education/rocket/rktcp.html</a></html>");

        // handle link events
        ep.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            @Override
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                if (HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED.equals(e.getEventType())) {
                    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                        try {
                            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(e.getURL().toURI());
                        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ep, "How To Use", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }    

    private void aboutButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent ab) throws IOException {

        aboutPopUp();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(panel);
        panel.add(aboutButton);
        aboutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ab) {
                try {
                    aboutButtonActionPerformed(ab);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(HyperlinkTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public HyperlinkTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new HyperlinkTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

Thank you guys in advance for any assistance you can provide, you all rock!!

Comment: What line does the stacktrace say the NPE is occurring?  I'm going to guess `e.getURL()` is returning null.

Comment: @MadConan Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at hyperlinktest.HyperlinkTest$1.hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkTest.java:45)

Comment: @MichaelMorgan Since I can't see line numbers here, which line is it?  What is the code on line 45?

Comment: @MadConan  Desktop.getDesktop().browse(e.getURL().toURI());

Comment: @MichaelMorgan :)  Use a debugger or System.out's to see what's null.  I'm still betting `null` is returned from `e.getURL()`.

Comment: @MadConan, ok if that is what is returning null, then how do I fix it?

Comment: @MichaelMorgan I'm not sure because I've never used these types of Objects.  But looking at your HTML:  Your anchor tags have no URL for them.  `href=""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
ep.setText("<html>Blah Blah<br />"
            + "Blah Blah<br />"
            + "Blah: <a     href=\\\"\\\">http://exploration.grc.nasa.gov/education/rocket/rktcg.html</a><br />"
            + "Blah: <a href=\\\"\\\">http://exploration.grc.nasa.gov/education/rocket/rktcp.html</a></html>");
```

I think what you want is

```
ep.setText("<html>Blah Blah<br />"
            + "Blah Blah<br />"
            + "Blah: <a href=\"http://exploration.grc.nasa.gov/education/rocket/rktcg.html\">http://exploration.grc.nasa.gov/education/rocket/rktcg.html</a><br />"
            + "Blah: <a href=\"http://exploration.grc.nasa.gov/education/rocket/rktcp.html\">http://exploration.grc.nasa.gov/education/rocket/rktcp.html</a></html>");
```

Note that **I have not compiled this**. You may need to escape things better/differently.

Also, you may want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889875/hyperlinkupdate-gives-me-nullpointerexception-every-time-i-click-a-hyperlink-i)

Comment: That worked!! thanks.  It makes more sense that way, set the destination after creating the link.  I should have known that.